# dipatchevent() isn't working in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, html, mobile-safari, createjs

I have recently developed an html5 game using createjs and I am currently in the testing phase. The game seems to work fine in all the devices except for the iPhone. 
After careful analysis I have come to a conclusion that the dispatchevent(), I'm employing in the code to run the createjs built-in rollover() function which I'm dispatching using the dispatchevent() isn't working in the IOS.Apart from this the game seems to be doing all the other tasks in the ios just fine. But since this is the main functionality I'm kind of stuck. The following is the code snipet where I'm employing the dispatchevent() :

```
                              o.dispatchEvent("rollover");
```

Any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: Is the `o` object a "tile", which has an active listener for "rollover"?

Comment: @Lanny Yes exactly .

Comment: @Lanny mate this problem is still eluding me, can you kindly look into it or point me in the right direction .Thanks

Comment: How does "rollover" work in iOS? Mobile devices don't have those kind of events.

Comment: @Lanny basically I have coded a touch-rollOver functionality for touch devices which is not a buit-in function of createjs. This function is working in all the touch devices , android , ipad etc but it is just not functioning in any version of the apple iPhone. 
This line o.dispatchEvent("rollover") dispatches just fine in every device expect for an iphone.

Answer (score -2):

You need to dispatch events for iphone in seperate.
So dispatch 2 ee

Comment: Sorry, Can you please elaborate?